# Why do Jelly submissions get to ignore the `Y` atom in the byte count?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

For those not familiar, `Y` in Jelly joins a list of strings (actually a list of lists of characters) with a newline. In plenty of challenges with text output, Jelly submissions will put `Y` in the footer on TIO, [which I have taken advantage of as well](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161187/75553). ([TIO with `Y`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDJdHDXN1rR/u6lY6POFR05qHO2cCScOHO2cBqf@H2yP//49WNzQ0MDAEQiCprsOloA5mIvMNUOUNwfJggMZHqDcAm2mgHgsA)).

Without `Y` the output would be the same text on a single line with no delimiter ([TIO without `Y`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDJdHDXN1rR/u6lY6POFR05qHO2cCScOHO2cBqf@H2///j1Y3NDQwMARCIKmuw6WgDmYi8w1Q5Q3B8mCAxkeoNwCbaaAeCwA)).

In the same challenge I linked to there is an [05AB1E submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/161176/75553) that returns a list of lines but the lines are clearly delimited in the output as elements of a list. In Jelly, however, any grouping of characters in lists gets ignored in the output.

My question is this: why do Jelly submissions get to forgo counting `Y` in the byte count if it is necessary to delimit portions of the output?

Not that I want my Jelly answers to have to have one extra byte from time to time, I just don't see the logic behind allowing this.

Comment: Note that in this case you're not allowed to use `³` or `⁴`, only `⁸` and `⁹`. (because function submission)

Answer (score 7):

A similar construct is actually visible in other languages, such as my "practical" language of choice C#, and is treated the same way. Here's a really simple challenge to use as an example:

---

Print this text:

```
Hello,
world!
```

---

Assuming "List of strings" is a valid alternative to "single string with newline delimiter", a simple C# answer might be this:

```
()=>new[]{"Hello,","world!"}
```

I think there are better options, but this is a valid solution to the challenge. However, a naive way to display that output [like so](https://tio.run/##NcyxCsIwFAXQ2XxFzJRA9QdquwjFQScHh9Ihvj40kCalL7VI6LfHVpQ73Qv3AO2AII1k3INf3xSwy5nTHVKvAXkfWT/erQEOVhNxiIyCDkuvRgcHCsPyq5uSP9Faz4skVVE6nOomitM6ZSITkx9suxVzyv/Yz3h50/KLNk6qyDZH78hb3N8GE/BsHMovKpXK2bwmfQA) results in an output of

```
System.String[]
```

Which clearly isn't requested! Instead, a [slightly more complex](https://tio.run/##NYy7CsIwFIbn5imOnVKovkDVRRAHnRwcikM8HjWQJiUnbZHgs8fWC//03z7kOTKmjrW9w/HJgZpKWNUQtwoJ2ija7mI0AhrFDBgFBxVGv@0sLjn48Vef1/AgYxyskixWa0tDfY75borKvMwH5811lr9S9Yf9GL3TVzgobWURRXZznhQ@ZK88GG0JtP1iZTHV2cZZdoYWJ68D7ceBnFZFJbKX@Ci9AQ) footer is needed to translate from "list of strings" to a human-readable format. Just like C#, Jelly (apparently) doesn't naturally format "output this list of strings" in a way that humans would like, so a Footer is added that translates from one *entirely valid* format to one *human readable* format.

Hopefully this example with a language that more clearly defines data types clears up that `Y` isn't used to make the answer valid, only to display a readable output.

Comment: +1, almost exactly what I had in mind. When you have an array in Java (`int[]array={1,2,3};`) and simply print it with `System.out.print(array);`, it uses the default `Object#toString` to print it (i.e. `[I@5ccd43c2`, where `[`=array; `I`=integer; `5ccd43c2`=some hexadecimal hashcode value). Using `System.out.print(java.util.Arrays.toString(array));` is similar to Jelly's `Y` (pretty-print builtin) resulting in `[1, 2, 3]`. Using `java.util.stream.IntStream.of(array).forEach(System.out::println);` is a custom pretty-print for a new-line delimited output. [TIO](https://tinyurl.com/yaf4a7rq)

Answer (score 4):

This would only be valid if the challenge would allow for output as a list of strings anyway. This is allowed on most ASCII-art challenges [and was allowed on the one you linked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/161169/ascii-art-to-numbers/161187#comment390478_161169). The solution would still be valid without the `Y`, it's just there to make the output look prettier.

Comment: The reason I’m not quite convinced by this is that while Jelly represents the output as a list of strings under the hood the output doesn’t and that’s what the user sees

Comment: @dylnan Jelly programs are also perfectly usable as Jelly functions. If you consider solutions to be functions rather than programs, the problem disappears.